# Conditional Formatting with Formula using Relative References

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I looked around for an answer to this and found a similar thread, but it did not quite answer my question so here goes.

I have two columns, each with 262,000 rows of data.  I am trying to highlight data in one of the columns based off of two conditions.  I think I have the formula right for the conditional formatting, but the problem is that it will not apply to the entire column as I want it to.  For example:

`=AND(K6<=1638, L6=0)`

That's the formula I have.  I want that formatting to copy and paste all the way down column K, iterating each time.  For example, the cell below should have formatting that says the following: `=AND(K7=1638, L7=0)` but I cannot get it to this.  It just keeps looking at the values in cells K6 and L6.

Is format painter not the way to get this formatting applied to each cell?

Comment: You cannot rely on usual Excel "formula dragging" when doing conditional formatting. You will need to rely on functions such as `ROW()`.

Comment: What range are you using for your Applies To:

Comment: @ScottCraner yep just as you said that, I realized that's the issue.  I tried it again, this time highlighting the entire range and using the same formula, this time it worked.  It doesn't really make sense to me because even though the entire range is highlighted, the formula still explicitly says "K6" and "L6" so I don't really know how it knows to iterate each time, but whatever I guess.

Comment: If you do not make the ranges in the formulas absolute then the conditional formatting will change the references based on the upper left cell.  If you have more than one column in your Applies To: you would want to make the column part of the references absolute.

Comment: So you're saying it really should be: `=AND($K$6<=1638, $L$6=0` ?

Comment: Oh wait, no you're not saying that. I understand now.  The conditional formatting only applies to column K.  It is, however, checking values in two different columns.

Comment: `=AND($K6<=1638, $L6=0` the row needs to be relative.

Comment: Weird.  I was able to do it without have to make it relative like that.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using conditional formatting as below?

I simplified the formula in the example but should work for your case as well.
It seems to me more practical for large ranges than Format Painter.

[image: Conditional formatting applying formula for each row]

The formula `=A2 > 4` has the cell `A2` hardcoded, yet it magically works when applied to cells `A6`, `A7`, etc.. Excel uses this formula in relation to the first cell in the range, so if you wanted to highlight cells in column `A` that are greater than column `B`, and your range started in `A2`, your formula would be `= A2 > B2`.

Comment: Yes, this is what you have to do it turns out.

Comment: The formula `=A2 > 4` has the cell `A2` hardcoded, yet it magically works when applied to cells A6, A7, etc.. but it's never explained how this works. What if I actually **want** to have a fixed reference to `A2` instead of `A{row}` - or vice-versa?

Comment: Excel uses this formula in relation to the first cell in the range, so if you wanted to highlight cells in column A that are greater than column B, and your range started in A2, your formula would be `= A2 > B2`.

Comment: @Dai fixed (aka absolute) references use the $ symbol. So $A$1 would always refer to exactly A1 .

Answer (score 1):

I suggest select Column K and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=AND(K1<=1638,L1=0)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select choice of formatting <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

When the rule is shown in the Conditional Formatting Rules Manager it is as applicable to the top left hand cell of the Applies to range. CF in effect raters through the range adjusting cell references automatically just as they adapt elsewhere (ie when going down Column K, `K1` scrolls forward to `K2` etc, whereas `K$1` would stay as `K$1`).

Answer (score -1):

You can do the conditional formatting you need by utilising `OFFSET()` and `ROW()` functions, so that your

```
=AND(K6<=1638, L6=0)
```

becomes something like:

```
=AND(OFFSET(K6,ROW()-6,0)<=1638, OFFSET(L6,ROW()-6,0)=0)
```

replace `-6` with the row offset value you need.

So, for example, if you enter this formula into some cell in row `6`, it will look into `K6` and `L6` respectively because `ROW()-6` evaluates to `0` – so no offset is applied.

Then in row `7` the **SAME** formula will look into `K7` and `L7` because `ROW()-6` evaluates to `1` which means offset one row below `K6` and `L6`.

Comment: This is way more complicated than just understanding how and when conditional formatting changes the relative references.

Comment: As far as I know conditional formatting does not take into account relative references.

Comment: Yes it is based on the upper left cell being the base cell. Then any relative reference will change based on where the cell is relative to the base cell.  So if you did =$A1=100 and Applied it to B:C every time that the Value in Column A = 100 Column B And column C in that row will return true and highlight.

Comment: I downvoted for the reasons @ScottCraner discusses. Using OFFSET is bad advice.